# Displaying DataTables warning: table id=example1 - Cannot reinitialise DataTable

Tags: datatables

Showing DataTables warning: table id=example1 - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error

**table**

```
<table class="data-table table table-bordered nowrap" id="example1">
```

**script**

```
$('#example1').dataTable( {
  paging: true,
  searching: true,
  destroy: true
} );
```

Comment: If I create a simple table using your code, and some static data in my HTML table, I do not see any errors. You can [edit] your question to provide more details, so that we can recreate the problem.

Comment: A very minor point (not relevant to your problem): Assuming you are using version 1.10 of DataTables, you typically initialize the Data Table using `$('#example1').DataTable( {...});` - not `$('#example1').dataTable( {...});`. Note the `D` vs. `d`. See [here](https://datatables.net/manual/api#Accessing-the-API) for a note about the difference between the two approaches.